# Idiom for something cheap that is expensive to replace

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

For example, a great pair of sunglasses which i paid a bargain for, but if they get lost or broken, I'll have to pay a lot to get as good a pair.

EDIT: I'm looking for the word that describes the current state of the sunglasses (from the example), not one that describes the initial purchase. Also, it could be something I *found* and didn't buy.

Comment: You might have been [upsold](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upsell) a [loss leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_leader). Suppose you used to wear cheap supermarket sunglasses, but your optician knows you'd never get your *prescription* glasses from anyone except him because there's no local competition. He might sell you your first pair of photosensitive (Reactolite) prescription glasses for the same price as the supermarket rubbish, knowing you'll replace them more often now (at the *full* price in future), because *now you'll wear (and **scratch**) them more.*

Comment: This is not, and the answers will not,  be an idiom.

Answer (score 3):

You could as well use **steal**.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com):

> 14. Informal. something acquired at a cost far below its real value; bargain:
>
> *This dress is a steal at $40*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "you got your original glasses for ***a bargain***"

> **Bargain**
> [bahr-guh n]
> /noun
>
> 1. an advantageous purchase, especially one acquired at less than the usual cost.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bargain)
> The sale offered bargains galore.

Comment: Perhaps emphasise this by saying a *real* bargain ;-)

Answer (score 1):

a sweet deal

a business or financial deal in which you get an advantage, pay a  low price etc

Usage: I got a sweet deal on the car.

source: Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

Comment: Just "deal" alone is also used for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for such a word (or short phrase) in the past and not found one. That probably means there isn't one in typical British English.

There are some terms which might help you though:

- "Replacement cost"/"replacement value" as in "it might have been cheap but it has a *high replacement value*"
- "Worth a lot *to me*". Note that this includes sentimental value.

Answer (score 1):

The OP was asking for an idiom which

> describes the current state of the sunglasses (from the example), not one that describes the initial purchase.

So it's not so much that it was cheap to purchase, but that it would be relatively expensive to replace.

To me, that speaks of an item which was once cheap and ubiquitous, but is now rare and hard to find, commanding a premium due to scarcity.  A few examples:

- A popular soda brand alters its flavor; disappointed consumers pay a premium for the remaining stock of the old formula
- A legal product becomes illegal, for example a slightly-too-dangerous toy
- The newer versions of a product are cheaper and flimsier than the old ones

In such a case I might say

- [**They don't make them like they used to**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/they+don%27t+make+them+like+they+used+to).
- This (pair of sunglasses) is an [**oldie but goodie**](https://grammarist.com/phrase/oldie-but-goodie/).

A decorative object or toy which was produced for a limited time may become a
[**collector's item**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/collector-s-item), in some cases prized more for its rarity than its intrinsic worth.

Further from the example of the sunglasses, media, such as music, books, and especially movies which were unappreciated at the time of release may become a [**cult classic**](https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/g33351370/best-cult-classic-movies/)